# nth-child td width stretching other elements?

Tags: css, html-table, css-selectors

I have a two column layout in sharepoint online and upon page inspection I can see that it has a table with two columns. I'm trying to hide one of the columns for printing, which is working just fine, but sharepoint has specified the width of the first column as 66%. It has no class or id. I cannot change this.

I am able to change the width of the column, but the problem I'm seeing is then that the % of the columns on the inside table is also changing, even when I use a specification of nth-child(1) on the id of the outer table.

I won't submit you to the mess of code that is sharepoint but the layout is like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="100%>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 25%>></td> <-this is getting stretched.
                            <td style="width: 25%>></td>
                            <td style="width: 25%>></td>
                            <td style="width: 25%>></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
@media print { 
    table#layoutsTable td:nth-child(1) {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mean only the first table child you need the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) `>`, e.g. `table#layoutsTable > td:nth-child(1) {...}`

Comment: Oh hey thanks - that worked perfectly.